# How can I implement this using Vue?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I'm immigrating my code to Vue.js so pretty new to Vue. As you see the screenshot(link below), There are 4 columns inside div with `columns` class name. and I was trying to use index, like `v-if='index % 4 === 0'` but I couldn't access to index out of `v-for` loop.

This is what I'm trying to make. 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/aO2Rx.png

```
<template lang="pug">
.container
  .columns // add this after every 4 coulmns
    .column.is-3.vid(v-for='(item,index) in items')
      .panel
        p.is-marginless
         a(:href='item.videoId')
           img(:src='item.thumbnail')
        .panel.vidInfo
          .columns.hax-text-centered
            .column
              .panel-item.reddit-ups
                span {{ item.score }}
                i.fa.fa-reddit-alien.fa-2x
              .panel-item.reddit-date
                i.fa.fa-calendar.fa-2x
</template>
```

Comment: Why would you render something that is related to the items in the v-for outside the v-for?

Comment: @Potray Do you think there's other ways to do this? check this https://i.stack.imgur.com/aO2Rx.png and tell me please!

Comment: Not without knowing the content of "items"

Comment: You can make a new array of 4-items chunks, for example with [lodash chunk](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#chunk). Then iterate twice.

Comment: @wostex ooh I was looking for some modules in lodash! thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

You can first divide items in groups of the appropriate size.
e.g Assuming `items` is an array on numbers 
`

```
var items = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
groupsLen = Math.ceil(items.length / 4)
var groups = [];
for(var i = 0; i < groupsLen; i++){
    var start = i * 4;
    var end = start + 4;
    groups.push(items.slice(start, end))
}
```

`
Then your template will look something like this( With each item as an object)

`

```
<template lang="pug">
.container
  .columns(v-for="group in groups") // add this after every 4 coulmns
    .column.is-3.vid(v-for='(item) in group')
      .panel
        p.is-marginless
         a(:href='item.videoId')
           img(:src='item.thumbnail')
        .panel.vidInfo
          .columns.hax-text-centered
            .column
              .panel-item.reddit-ups
                span {{ item.score }}
                i.fa.fa-reddit-alien.fa-2x
              .panel-item.reddit-date
                i.fa.fa-calendar.fa-2x
</template>`
```